reading the data via scanning the QR-code
I have to deferent domain one "knu.edu.af" two "mis.knu.edu.af". Both registered in one host but the "mis.knu.edu.af" its data is located in another server and I pointed the domain to server via an IP address. Up to this level all things work correctly.
The issue is this: I have a page for QR-code in files of "knu.edu.af", this has the codes to read the data from "mis.knu.edu.af".
For every one I have a specific QR-code, when I scan this QR-code it redirect me to "knu.edu.af" then it read that page for QR-code codes, and then for reading the main data it has a code to connect this QR-code to "mis.knu.edu.af", in this level the things is not working.
Could please guide me what should I do?
I'm going to share the QR-code image and the codes with you.
This the image of QR-code
Bellow is the code for reading the data:QR
<?php

$code = $_GET['code'];
$json = file_get_contents('https://mis.knu.edu.af/studentDetails/get/'.$code);
$info=json_decode($json);

?>

    
    
    
    پوهنتون خاتم النبیین (ص)
    
    
    
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'nazanin';
            font-style: normal;
            src: url('https://knu.edu.af/fonts/bnazanb.ttf')  format('truetype');
        }
        * {
            direction: rtl;
            font-family: 'nazanin';
        }
        .borderless td, .borderless th {
            border: none !important;
        }
        .form-signin
        {
            max-width: 330px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .account-wall
        {
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }
        .login-title
        {
            color: #555;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 400;
            display: block;
        }
        .profile-img
        {
            width: 126px;
            margin: 0 auto 10px;
            display: block;
            -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
    


if($info):
if($info->type == "student"){
?>




پوهنتون خاتم النبیین (ص)

                    <? if (@getimagesize("http://mis.knu.edu.af".$info->data->photo_url)): ?>
                        <img class="profile-img" src="http://mis.knu.edu.af<?= $info->data->photo_url ?>" alt="<?= isset($info->data->name) ? $info->data->name : null ?> <?= isset($info->data->last_name) ? $info->data->last_name : null ?>">
                    <? else: ?>
                        <img class="profile-img" src="http://mis.knu.edu.af/images/avatar-placeholder.png" alt="">
                    <? endif; ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table class="table borderless">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left; width:50%">کد دانشجویی</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->code) ? $info->data->code : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">نام و تخلص</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->name) ? $info->data->name : null ?> <?= isset($info->data->last_name) ? $info->data->last_name : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">نام پدر</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->father_name) ? $info->data->father_name : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">نام پدرکلان</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->grandfather_name) ? $info->data->grandfather_name : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">رشته</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->department) ? $info->data->department : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">مجموع کریدتها</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->totalCredits) ? $info->data->totalCredits : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">کریدتهای پاس شده</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->passedCreadits) ? $info->data->passedCreadits : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">کریدتهای ناکام </td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->failedCredits) ? $info->data->failedCredits : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">فیصدی عمومی</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->finalAverage) ? $info->data->finalAverage : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">وضعیت</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->status) ? $info->data->status : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">سال شمولیت</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->year) ? $info->data->year : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">سال فراغت</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->graduation_year) ? $info->data->graduation_year : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<?php } ?>


<?php

if($info->type == "teacher"){
?>




پوهنتون خاتم النبیین (ص)

                    <? if (@getimagesize("http://mis.knu.edu.af".$info->data->photo_url)): ?>
                        <img class="profile-img" src="http://mis.knu.edu.af<?= $info->data->photo_url ?>" alt="<?= isset($info->data->name) ? $info->data->name : null ?> <?= isset($info->data->last_name) ? $info->data->last_name : null ?>">
                    <? else: ?>
                        <img class="profile-img" src="http://mis.knu.edu.af/images/avatar-placeholder.png" alt="">
                    <? endif; ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table class="table borderless">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left; width:50%">کد</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->code) ? $info->data->code : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">نام و تخلص</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->name) ? $info->data->name : null ?> <?= isset($info->data->last_name) ? $info->data->last_name : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">نام پدر</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->father_name) ? $info->data->father_name : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">نام پدرکلان</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right"><?= isset($info->data->grandfather_name) ? $info->data->grandfather_name : null ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">سمت اداری</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right">استاد</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:left">وضعیت</td>
                                <td style="text-align:right">{{($info->data->active == 1) ? "فعال" : "غیرفعال" }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<?php } ?>



<?php

if($info->type == "employee"){
echo "E";
?>




پوهنتون خاتم النبیین (ص)

data->photo_url)): ?>
data->photo_url ?>" alt="data->name) ? $info->data->name : null ?> data->last_name) ? $info->data->last_name : null ?>">







کد
data->code) ? $info->data->code : null ?>


نام و تخلص
data->name) ? $info->data->name : null ?> data->last_name) ? $info->data->last_name : null ?>


نام پدر
data->father_name) ? $info->data->father_name : null ?>


نام پدرکلان
data->grandfather_name) ? $info->data->grandfather_name : null ?>


سمت اداری
data->job_title) ? $info->data->job_title : null ?>


وضعیت
{{ ($info->data->active == 1) ? "فعال" : "غیرفعال" }}




            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<?php } ?>

   
  این سرویس به علت بروزرسانی در دسترس نمی باشد
   


